# Show and hide images with div

Tags: javascript, hide, show

Alright, I want to edit this code so if I for example press button 1 it first shows an image and then if I press button 1 again it should hide the image. Same goes for all buttons. I wonder if someone can rewrite my script so that becomes possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .hidden {
    display: none;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
window.show = function(elementId) { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        elements[i].className = "hidden";

    document.getElementById(elementId).className = "";
}
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="show('id1');" >Button 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show('id2');" >Button 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show('id3');">Button 3</button>

<button type="button" onclick="show('id4');">Button 4</button>

<div id="id1" class="hidden"><img  src="alfagel.gif" height="280" width="120"/></div>
<div id="id2" class="hidden"><img  src="alfagel.gif" height="280" width="120"/></div>
<div id="id3" class="hidden"><img  src="bjorktrast.gif" height="280" width="120"/></div>
<div id="id4" class="hidden">text 4</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Consider jQuery and use jQuery.toggleClass along with your .hidden class. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: @Tsalikidis mind to change the code for me? :) I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

[Import jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

[Use $.fn.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$('div').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLLL7/

Comment: Where you should put the code depends on what you need to achive at the end. I'm unable to know this so i just give you a general example.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a hide and show method that should work. Example:

```
$('id1').hide()
```

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way to do this would be to use jQuery and look into it's toggle() function. Otherwise..perhaps store the states of the buttons as boo leans and hide/show conditionally based on the value.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure where to put the jQuery code though.